# Can i send and receive emails using ActionMailer in development env.?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am trying to design a email confirmation but not able to receive emails in my gmail account. Can anyone help ?

Comment: We can help if you give more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. one-step confirmation in gmail does not work;
2. you must enable 2-step gmail verification and enable app password;
3. dotenv doesn't load the passwords to production - you have to feed heroku in CLI heroku config:set var1=value1, etc. or at the link https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/<your_application>/settings (this last tip does not apply to development).

For a specific trouble, please:
a) detail the code and error; or
b) make available your public repository in github.